# How to get the last person who modified a file in Git?

Tags: git

Can I find out who modified given file last?

Can I also find out a list of changesets which affected a given file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This command should give you all the commits that changed this file with the diff. You can also see who made this commit.

```
git log -p <filepath>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question but found that the previous answers do not limit the output to the person as the OP asked.

Following will show the author with his/her email.

```
git log -s -n1 --pretty='format:%an %ae%n' <filepath>
```

see https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats for more format options

Answer (score 4):

Try [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log -n 1 -- path/to/file.html
```

`-n 1` makes it only load the latest commit.